# über einen Satz in der Nähe der Mittelburg

Tags: meaning, phrase

Letzes Jahr war ich in [Neckarsteinach](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neckarsteinach), wo ich zurzeit wohne, und in der Nähe der [Mittelburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelburg_(Neckarsteinach)) gibt es viele Mauern und Monumenten, auf denen man Sätze auf Deutsch lesen kann (z.B. [CLIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcna8.jpg)). Damals fand ich ein "Monument",  auf denen ich den folgenden Satz, den ich  durch zwei Foto zeige, nicht verstehen konnte:
[image] [image]
Ich erkenne ein paar Wörter aus Deutsch, wie das Wort *das **C**reuz* (warum mit **C** und nicht mit **K** ??), das Verb *anbeten*, die Konjunktion *sondern*, den Artikel *der*, den Rest leider nicht und vor allem das erste Wort (*NIT* ??). Trotzdem bin ich nicht sicher, ob ich die wenige Wörter richtig erkenne und ich frag mich, ob das vielleicht eine besondere "dialektale" Forme der deutschen Sprache ist, deshalb bitte ich jemanden um Hilfe.

ps=Ich bitte Sie um Verzeihung, falls die Frage *off topic* oder der Titel nicht adäquat ist

Comment: It reads *Nit das creuz holtz betet an sonder der gehängen daran*. Today one would write *Nicht das Holzkreuz betet an, sondern den der gehangen daran.* which translates into *Do not pray to the wooden cross but to the one who hung from it.*

Comment: @Janka, danke! Jetzt verstehe..

Comment: @Janka y u no proper answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Spruch lautet "nit das creuzholtz betet an, sondern der gehangen daran", was inhaltlich bedeutet, dass man nicht das Kreuz, also das Holz anbeten soll, sondern den, der daran gekreuzigt wurde. 
Einige Gegenden in Österreich sagen *nit* anstatt *nicht*. Nach Norden zu wird das dann zu *ned*.
Die Schreibweise *Creuz* wurde ca. 1800 durch *Kreuz* ersetzt.

Comment: ich danke dir für die Erklärungen! :) Ich dachte, vielleicht *nit* ist ein Fehler, aber so ist das nicht! Außerdem wusste ich nicht, dass Einige Gegenden in Österreich *nit* anstatt *nicht* sagen. Gut zu wissen, falls ich das in Österreich höre! ich danke dir noch mal..

Comment: Die genauen Gegenden kannst du hier erfahren: http://www.bym.de/forum/welt/472993-frage-oesterreicher-dialekt.html

Comment: Interessant! Was kann ich sagen? Noch mal danke! :)